# JavaScript class vs function returning object

Tags: javascript, playwright, pageobjects

So im pretty much used to always using classes when writing automation code (Using the Page object Model). However i've came across some PoM/Component sample code that im not really used to seeing. For example this `header.ts` file is not what I am used to seeing:

```
import { Page, expect } from "@playwright/test";

export function Header(page: Page) {
  const self = page.locator('header');

  const input = self.getByPlaceholder('What needs to be done?');
  const toggleAllButton = page.getByLabel('Mark all as complete');

  const completeAll = () => toggleAllButton.check();
  const uncompleteAll = () => toggleAllButton.uncheck();
   
  const addTodo = async (text: string) => {
    await input.fill(text);
    await input.press('Enter');
  }; 

  return {
    addTodo,
    completeAll,
    uncompleteAll,
    expect: () => ({
      ...expect(self),
      toAllowUncompleteAll: (allow = true) => expect(toggleAllButton).toBeChecked({ checked: allow }),
      toHaveEmptyInput: () => expect(input).toBeEmpty()
    })
  };
}
```

Now this is using Playwright specifically, but the object/component model is similar. In classes you don't typically "return" anything, but here they are returning all the functions to be used elsewhere.

I guess my main question is:

1. Why do we have to return the functions within here as opposed to a class once you create the instance object we don't have to return anything.
2. Is there really any advantage to doing it this way vs a class? (Feels messier?)
3. I don't under the `...expect(self)` and what that is doing. To be honest why is `self` used here anyways? (Im not familiar with how self works in functions)

Comment: `self` is just a variable. (Well, a constant, but it's just a name.)

Comment: This is a style that was often used before ES6 classes.

Comment: Well… there's no *class* here. What you're looking at is a function. A function that returns an object.

Comment: The code you posted *is* returning an object with the functions, not just the functions. `{}` is shorthand for "object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's the [Revealing Module Design Pattern](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-javascript-design/9781449334840/ch09s03.html).

By using this you can simply define all functions and variables in the private scope and return an anonymous object with pointers to the private functionality to expose to other code areas where required utilizing [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

> This is a very clean way of specifying the public functions that you
> want to expose to the outside world. I think , the biggest advantage
> of revealing module pattern is that provides **cleaner code
> structure**.

The revealing module pattern is used to provide an abstraction over private implementations by providing public APIs. I think more or less we achieve the same thing using classes.

Simple Code Example:

```
// JavaScript Revealing Module Pattern
const Person = (function () {
  // Private Properties
  let name;
  let lastName;

  function publicSetName(_name, _lastName) {
    name = _name;
    lastName = _lastName;
  }

  function publicGetName() { return `${name} ${lastName}` }

  /**
   * Reveal public pointers to 
   * private functions and properties
   */
  return {
    setName: publicSetName,
    getName: publicGetName
  }
})();

const client = Person;

client.setName('Vishu', 'A.');
console.log(client.getName()); // Vishu A.
// The name property is not accessible.
console.log(client.name); // undefined
```

This was used to emulate the concept of classes earlier but including public/private properties and methods, protecting certain parts from the global scope by the use of closures.

In my personal opinion , I find it more cleaner solution than [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

For further Reading: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/module-design-pattern-vs-classes-in-javascript-45568e74ad2a

Comment: Thank you moderators @deceze  for pointing out my mistake in the last answer. It took me whole night to explore the concept fully (and all the related concepts around it with trade-offs) but it was the rewarding experience in the end. I learnt something.